# OBS Studio v25.03 is starting every time I log into KDE, how can I disable?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde, autostart, obs-studio

After every reboot or boot of Kubuntu OBS starts automatically.
I think this happens since about a month.

#### I tried:

- I disabled all checkbox [ ] at
  Settings>General>System Tray (one was enabled, this Checkbox [x] Enable)
- searched in the Autostart-Menü of kUbuntu

#### i have read:

OBS is starting every time I log into KDE, how can I disable?
https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/obs-is-starting-every-time-i-log-into-kde-how-can-i-disable.96962/

#### workaround: kill obs seconds after OS starts:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2s # better wait 2 seconds. seems at 22-0920_0921-53 OS was freezes without waiting seconds
killall /usr/bin/obs &> /dev/null # works :) 22-0920_0900-57
```

## System:

`OBS 25.03+dfsg1-2(linux)`

```
System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-46-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```